# How to include section name in Latex article

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to include section names in the header of my latex article using the fancyhdr package.
However, after having tried various options there seems to be another package blocking the command.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Please find the loaded packages below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % paper and 12pt font size %kan nog naar 11pt
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thesection\quad #1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
\savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
  \scaleto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
  }{\textheight}% 
}{0.5ex}}%
\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{\mathbb{V}ar}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\usepackage{fullpage}
%\usepackage{times}
%\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[citebordercolor={1 1 1}, linkbordercolor={1 1 1}, urlbordercolor={1 1 1}]{hyperref}
\newcommand\solidcirc[4][0]{\rotatebox{#1}{\tikz{\draw[line width=#2] (0,0) 
  arc [x radius=#3,y radius=#4,start angle=0,end angle=360];}}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bbone}{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\EX}{\mathbb{E}}% expected value
\let\estinput=\input
\usepackage{dcolumn}    % aligning decimals
    \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
    

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            %\textsymbols% Note the added command here
            \begin{tabular*}
            {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \\ \bottomrule}}
```

Comment: What is the pagestyle your are using in the actual document? Your code shown declared to page styles, the `fancy` from `fancyhdr` and a new one called `classica`, and they have different definitions.

Comment: And **please clean up your preamble**. It is loading `caption` at least **five separate times** by my count, `xcolors` at least three times (not always with the same set of options), and if you are copying this from your production document, there is no point to load `mwe` or `lipsum`. Those two packages are only useful for creating test documents.

Comment: @WillieWong thank you for your response. I cleaned up the preamble, I know it was a mess sorry for that. Regarding the pagestyle, I am new to using these kind packages so I guess I should just stick to the fancy style? I included the classica one because I found an example using that pagestyle. Any thoughts on how to include the headers?

Comment: Are you sure your document actually compiles? Your preamble didn't load `sectsty`, yet you are using `\sectionfont`. Your preamble as listed cannot possibly be from a document that actually builds. (I just copied it and put in some dummy text in `\begin{document}` and it fails to build.) First resolve all of the errors that show up in the log file/console. Once you do that maybe we can track down your issue with `fancyhdr`.

Comment: @WillieWong thank you for your swift response. Yes I am sure my document compiles, I am using overleaf..

Comment: I just tried loading the preamble in another doc and it compiled as well, I removed sectionfont @WillieWong

Comment: Solved! :) It was \usepackage{fullpage} causing the issue. Thanks a lot for your help anyways! Much appreciated.